# Plotting function with respect to a keyword argument leads to error in Julia

Tags: function, plot, julia

I have a function which involves bunch of integrals and complicated computations, like the following:

```
using HCubature
function func(v, x0, y0; rad=1.)

    L = hcubature(r->r[1]*v(x0+r[1]*cos(r[2]), y0+r[1]*sin(r[2])), [0., π/2], [rad, π])[1]
    R = hcubature(r->r[1]*v(x0+r[1]*cos(r[2]), y0+r[1]*sin(r[2])), [0., 0], [rad, π/2])[1]

    return L, R

end
```

The argument `v` is a function itself. 
When I try to plot the function with respect to the keyword argument `rad`, I obtain error messages as follows:

```
x0_, y0_ = 0, 0

rad_ = 0.:0.1:9.

func_array_L = [func(v, x0_, y0_; rad = radius)[1] for radius in rad_]
func_array_R = [func(v, x0_, y0_; rad = radius)[2] for radius in rad_]

plot(rad_, func_array_L)
plot!(rad_, func_array_R)
```

The error message includes a very long error message: `Internal error: encountered unexpected error in runtime:` then followed by a long list of directories, and then it comes to the following:

```
MethodError: no method matching string(::Expr)
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 3820, while current world is 26290.
Closest candidates are:
  string(::Any...) at strings/io.jl:168 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
  string(!Matched::String) at strings/substring.jl:152 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
  string(!Matched::SubString{String}) at strings/substring.jl:153 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
  ...
```

I tried also other methods like declaring another function with `rad` as the only argument, etc. but none of them worked. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the error message is strange, but the reason is simple. You have not defined the function `v`. You should define it first, and then all should work as expected.

Additionally note that you have a wrong case in `using HCubature` (note that `u` should be lowercase). Also in order for plotting to work you should firs import a plotting package e.g. by `using Plots`.

#### EDITS

A basic code that reproduces your problem is:

```
julia> using HCubature

julia> function func(v, x0, y0; rad=1.)
           L = hcubature(r->r[1]*v(x0+r[1]*cos(r[2]), y0+r[1]*sin(r[2])), [0., π/2], [rad, π])[1]
           R = hcubature(r->r[1]*v(x0+r[1]*cos(r[2]), y0+r[1]*sin(r[2])), [0., 0], [rad, π/2])[1]
           return L, R
       end
func (generic function with 1 method)

julia> v = (x,y) -> x
#27 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x0_, y0_ = 0, 0
(0, 0)

julia> rad_ = 0.:0.1:9.
0.0:0.1:9.0

julia> func_array_L = [func(v, x0_, y0_; rad = radius)[1] for radius in rad_]
Internal error: encountered unexpected error in runtime:
MethodError(f=typeof(Base.string)(), args=(Expr(:<:, :t, :r),), world=0x0000000000000eec)
```

This seems to be a bug. I reported it [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33421).

#### A workaround

Now - the way to solve it is to make `v` type stable. There are three example ways to do it.

Option 1: define it as `const`:

```
const v1 = v
```

and use a comprehension with `v1` passed instead of `v`.

Option 2: wrap it in `let` block:

```
func_array_L = let v=v
    [func(v, x0_, y0_; rad = radius)[1] for radius in rad_]
end
```

Option 3: define a function with a name using `v`:

```
v2(x,y) = v(x,y)
```

and use a comprehension with `v2` passed instead of `v`.

Alternatively you could also make `x0_` or `y0_` to be of constant type (it is enough to fix one of them) to make all work. E.g. this

```
func_array_L = [func(v, 1, y0_; rad = radius) for radius in rad_]
```

works as expected.

#### Additional notes

You have a similar problem if you use `map` instead of a comprehension if in map you use an anonymous function:

```
map(radius -> func(v, x0_, y0_; rad = radius)[1], rad_)
```

and also a normal function that has a name produces the same error:

```
v3(radius) = func(v, x0_, y0_; rad = radius)[1]
map(v3, rad_)
```

but it starts to work if you make an internal function that is introduced into a method-table:

```
v3(radius) = (tmp(x...) = v(x...); func(tmp, x0_, y0_; rad = radius)[1])
```

and now `map(v3, rad_)` works as expected.

Comment: I have defined it. It's just I haven't listed here how I defined the function. That involves a bunch of interpolations which is irrelevant so I simply neglected it. And I also imported Plots, I also didn't include that here. And I didn't get wrong with `using` in the original code, I corrected that in the question already.

Comment: When I define `v` e.g. as `v(x,y) = x` all works correctly. So it seems that in order to diagnose your problem it would be needed to analyze how `v` works.

Comment: `v` is a function obtained from `Interpolations.jl`, and I have tried `func(v, x0_, y0_; rad = radius)[1]` and substitute `radius` with different numbers, and they're all single Float64 numbers and I don't obtain any error messages. So I don't understand why it doesn't work once I turn to list comprehension for plotting.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce it. I will comment in the answer. The problem is when `v` is an anonymous function. I will comment how you can work around this in the answer.

Comment: I have added some comments. It seems to be a bug.

Comment: It seems the problem is only on Julia 1.2. On Julia 1.3 and 1.0.4 LTS it works OK.